# How long does it take a closed question to be deleted?

Tags: support

Maybe it's just me, but I really dislike my questions being marked [CLOSED] and if there's already answers I'm unable to delete the question.  How long does it take a closed question to be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you ever wanted to know about Closed questions, but were afraid to ask: 
[What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

Which leads to:

Everything you ever wanted to know about Deleted posts, but never knew to ask: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)